# изменение переменной пользователем

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Есть такая строчка в html:

```
<div>Любимый цвет: синий <button>(изменить)</button></div>
```

Подскажите как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку изменить появлялось:

```
<div> Любимый цвет: <select><option>Синий</option><option>Красный</option></select><button>Подтвердить</button>
```

И при нажатии на "Подтвердить" Соответственно закреплялся новый цвет. Притом закрепляться он должен в бд сразу. Есть понимание, как отправить новые данные через ajax в бд, но как сделать это самое изменение туда-сюда - нет. Подскажите кто может.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тегу button присвоить класс, на класс повесить обработчик на событие onclick. Внутри обработчика прописать замену button с классом на select.

```
Любимый цвет: синий <button class='js-replace-button'>(изменить)</button>

<script>
  $('button.js-replace-button').click(fuction(){
    $(this).html('<select>...</select>');
  });
</script>
```

На кнопку подтвердить, также вешаешь обработчик, но там уже с вызовом ajax.